# Replacing sepecific values with their previous value

Tags: matlab, replace

I deal with the size distribution of sediment particles.

```
row : 1~50
column : 1~10

commonly, row 1 :

[0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.002   0.014 0.010 0.015   0
0.020   0.073   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9.104 0 0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

Almost, the rows have this trend..
in here, I have to remove the outlier.

removing method (Richard Styles, 2013).
outlier is identified by first computing the difference, as defined by `Y_i+1 - Y_i`, where `Y_i` is the 'it's data point, and then removing all values greater than `R` times the absolute value of the mean of this difference for a given profile.
`R` is adjustable..

And next. I don't know. how can replace `RM_point` of `Row` with the previous `Row` value.

```
Dif = abs(diff(st2.ex_dep_1m(1,26:75), 1, 2)); 
M_Dif = mean(Dif, 2); 
RM_point = find(Dif(1,:) >= M_Dif*3);
st2.ex_dep_1m(1, RM_point(1,2))

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.002   0.014 0.010 0.015   0   
0.020   0.073   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9.104 0 0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

in this matrix, `9.104` is the outlier. Thus, I want to replace `9.10`4 with `0`, but, there are other cases that we have to consider this condition.

- ex1) if there are several instances of `RM_point`
- ex2) when implementing the `diff` function, there are equal values in `Row`.
   because from `Row [0 9 0]` follows `diff [-9 9]` which results in `abs [9 9]`, but actually, `Row` has only one 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make more general your code and to be able to capture the cases

> - ex1) if there are several instances of RM_point
> - ex2) when implementing the diff function, there are equal values in Row.
>     because from Row [0 9 0] follows diff [-9 9] which results in abs [9 9], but actually, Row has only one 9

you should search for the values `>= M_Dif*3` (the `RM_point` points) within the original set of data and not in the `Dif` array.

In the following you can find the updated code; in order to make easier understanding the results I've modified the input data as follows:

- removed some `0` to keep the array "shorter"
- inserted some additional values to be removed (`3.12 9.104`)
- the updated array contains now three consecutive `9.104` values to demnstrate to answer to `ex1` and `ex2` cases of you question

Also, in the code, I've set the value to be used toi replace the the `RM_point` to the threshold value (`M_Dif*3`) again, just to make more understandable the relsult.

```
% Modified input row:
%   some "0" removed
%   replaced 4 "0" with 3.21 9.104   9.104 9.104
%
st2.ex_dep_1m=[  0   0   0.002   0.014 0.010 0.015   0, ...
   0.020   0.073   0     0   3.21   0   0   9.104   9.104 9.104 0   0   0   0, ...
   0    0   0   0   0]
% Create a copy of the original row to make easier verify the result
st2.ex_dep_1m_CLEAN=st2.ex_dep_1m

Dif = abs(diff(st2.ex_dep_1m, 1, 2)); 
M_Dif = mean(Dif, 2); 
% Identify the points to be removed within the original row
% RM_point = find(Dif(1,:) >= M_Dif*3);
RM_point = find(st2.ex_dep_1m >= M_Dif*3);
% Set the points to be removed to the threshold (to better visualize them)
% st2.ex_dep_1m(1, RM_point(1,2))
st2.ex_dep_1m_CLEAN(1, RM_point)=M_Dif*3

% Plot the Original and the Modified row
a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(st2.ex_dep_1m,'o','markerfacecolor','k')
legend('Original')
grid on
a2=subplot(2,1,2)
plot(st2.ex_dep_1m_CLEAN,'o','markerfacecolor','r')
grid on
legend('Cleaned')
% Adjust the ylim
a1y=get(a1,'ylim')
a2y=get(a1,'ylim')
y_lim=[min([a1y a2y]) max([a1y a2y])]
set([a1 a2],'ylim',y_lim)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.